# What does it mean for a machine language to be Turing-complete?

Tags: turing-machines, turing-completeness, theory

I was reading the Wikipedia article on Turing completeness, but I was having a hard time putting together all of the concepts. In simple terms, what does it mean for an instruction set to have Turing-completeness?

Comment: It means that you can compute with it anything that you can on your regular computer (or equivalently, on Turing Machines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A turing complete program means it can do anything a Turing Machine can do. Ok, what in the world is a Turing Machine? Well, Alan Turing had a brillant idea, a made up machine which has a infinitely long piece of tape (otherwise known as memory). The machine also has a head, which can do 3 things:

1. Read the symbol on the square under the head.
2. Edit the symbol by writing a new symbol or erasing it.
3. Move the tape left of right by one square so that the machine can read and edit the symbol on a neighbouring square.

With only these simple components, a turing machine can theoretically compute anything given enough time. So, a computer language is said to be turing complete if it can do what the turing machine can, or in other words run any computer problem given enough time and memory.